# Разбить HTML массив по строкам / колонкам

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть скрипт https://script.google.com/d/1Mc8BthYthXx6CoIz90-JiSzSafVnT6U3t0z_W3hLTAX5ek4w0G_EIrNw/edit?usp=drive_web, который используется в качестве библиотеки. В моем коде я получаю ошибку "Не удается обнаружить функцию split в объекте"  Как разбить текст используя в качестве разделителя для строк br, а разделителя для колонок тег th?

```
function getData3(cell1) {

 var url = "http://quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=AHL-D&sopt=symbol";

Logger.log(url);
var fromText = '<font size="2">';
var toText = '</font>';

var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var scraped = Parser
                .data(content)
                .from(fromText)
                .to(toText)
                .iterate();
var array1 = [{}];
var string1 = scraped;

array1 = string1.split('<br>');

  Logger.log(scraped);
  return array1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parser_.prototype.iterate` возвращает массив.

Вероятно, вам нужно что-то вроде

```
array1 = string1.map(function(item){
  return item.split('<br>');
});
```